# Parsing support in vscode namespace

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

VS Code has basic parsing support out of the box (e.g. [highlighting matching brackets, line comments and block comments](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/colorizer)). Is it possible to use this parser in an extension or do you know of a good parser that is accessible from TypeScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sam Harwell is [working on a TS runtime](https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4ts) for the [ANTLR tool](http://www.antlr.org), which I started using in an vscode extension to parse text. Still in early alpha state but already usable.

Comment: Yes, PEG.js looks good as well. I had this once considered for a new project. However, it's all a matter of taste, I guess. I'm much more familiar with ANTLR. If you are new to both, pick the one with the easier start and stronger community.